# How to create different registration form in Drupal7 when anonymous user can't view published pages?

Tags: drupal-7

To resolve this problem on my own, I started out by installing Profile2 and Profile2 registration.  At no point was I able to generate a page based on the user name (eg, `{domain}/private/register`).  I figured it was not coming up b/c I checked off that anonymous users could not see published pages (which is a site requirement).  However, I might have done something wrong but I went over the instructions several time and I don't think I made a mistake.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have to create a new content type, similar to the normal story or article types, and publish restricted content as the new page type. Apply the access restriction to this content type, and leave the default content types alone.

Comment: Bart, I will give you credit for the suggestion.  Thanks for the idea I have a lot of work to do.